# uploading only one image second shows me error in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to save array of multi images and values , the values was saving well but when i going to add image it's only save one image and upload only one .

Here's my controller function

```
public function store(Request $request) {

$parentproduct = new Product();
    $parentproduct->id = Input::get('id');
    $parentproduct->save();
    $insertedId = $parentproduct->id;
    $uploadcount=0;


$files = Input::file('main_image');
 $file_count = count($files);

 foreach($files as $i=>$file) {

$multiupload=new ProductsTranslation();

if($request->hasFile('main_image')){

$destinationPath = 'website/images';
$filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
$upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
$uploadcount ++;
$multiupload->main_image = $filename;
 $multiupload->id = $request->input('id')[$i];
 $multiupload->title = $request->input('title')[$i];
 $multiupload->language = $request->input('language')[$i];
 $multiupload->product_id=$parentproduct->id;
 $multiupload->save();




}



}
```

It's working fine after the final update ...

Comment: could you show us your form please?

Comment: try to add `[]` after your name atrr so it will look like this `main_image[]`

Comment: It's getting me this error : 

Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object

Comment: could you `dd(Input::file('main_image'))` at the top of your `store` method to see if you get all your images or not?

Comment: Yes , it get me double images

Comment: I would say to comment any function that blocks the upload process to see if your files get uploaded or not then you could handle inserting them in the database later

Comment: I have comment all lines that save to DB , but it didn't upload any file

Comment: It's getting me that : Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object and didn't upload anyting

Comment: I think the problem is in `$filename` variable what `getClientOriginalName()` should do?

Comment: It's getting the name of the image

Comment: when i trying this var_dump($request->file('main_image')); 
It's back with the value not null

Comment: You told me that gave you  two images and `dd(Input::file('main_image'))`?

Comment: yes, it's show them

Comment: Could you add to your post what the data looks like? IF you found yourself you need to go to sleep you can do that and we can continue tomorrow feel free to do that

Comment: One thing i've just noticed why you add your file loop into the language loop try to separate them

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if (Input::hasFile('main_image')) {
    foreach (Input::file('main_image') as $file) {
         $destinationPath = 'website/images';
         $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
         $upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
         $uploadcount ++;


// You have to initialize your array out side your loop
   $insertprod = [];
    foreach ($request->input('language') as $i=>$language) {
    $insertprod[] = array(
                'id' =>$request->input('id')[$i], 
                'product_id'=>$parentproduct->id,
                'title' =>$request->input('title')[$i],
                'language' => $request->input('language')[$i], 
                //used this line to save the image name path !
                'main_image'=>$filename[$i]

             );     

    }

  }
  DB::table('products_translations')->insert($insertprod);
}
```

Comment: Thank you , i did , but still have the same issue

Comment: Yes didn't upload the images , But i have updated the code and get me an array but just with the last uploading image ( get it's name only but not uploaded ) . 
and get the last one and doubled them . 
I will update my code to can see that .

Comment: When i remove the second foreach , the 2 images has been uploaded successfully, but I don't know how to save them at the array of data to DB .

Comment: I think we have to make the for loop inside each other to see the uploaded image value , i have tried your answer but getting that error : 
Creating default object from empty value
at that line :  'main_image'=>$multiupload->fileimage = $filename,

Comment: I have tried this only get the first digit of the name for each image

Comment: I think we have to save the image names at the first foreach after uploaded it directly , but i don't know how to save the others data with it

Comment: Finally , It's working good !  I will update my question with the final code . 

Thank you very mutch for your help :)

Comment: We are here to help each other. But Please Don't update your question if you get the answer on your own post it as an answer.

Comment: Sorry, i have added it yesterday already , I updated if to help someone want it. I wasn't know that . There's place to the ansewer ! sorry

Comment: Don't be, that's because may some one is facing the exact same problem you had so when he searches his question could found your question not your answer directly without knowing what the question was. next time i hope you will remember my words :)